# Clipping shapefile with multi-polygon shapefile in geopandas

Tags: python, geopandas, shapefile, clip

I have a shapefile (will be called source-file hereafter), which I need to clip by a multi-polygon shapefile so that I can have a clipped shapefile for each polygon. I tried the geopandas, though I am able to clip the source-file by individually clipping the it by selecting the polygons separately from the multi-polygon shapefile, but when I try to loop over the polygons  to automate the clipping process I get the following error:

Error:
TypeError: 'mask' should be GeoDataFrame, GeoSeries or(Multi)Polygon, got <class 'tuple'>

Code:

```
import geopandas as gpd

source = ('source-shapefile.shp')
mask = ('mask_shapefile.shp')
sourcefile = gpd.read_file(source)
maskfile = gpd.read_file(mask)
for row in maskfile.iterrows():
    gpd.clip(sourcefile, row)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, after 5 hours of research, I am now able clip the shapefile by a multi-polygon shapefile and save the clipped polygons separately with their respective names. Following code may be dirty
but it works.
code:

```
import geopandas as gpd
import pandas as pd
import os, sys

source = ('source-shapefile.shp')
mask = ('mask_shapefile.shp')
outpath = ('/outpath')

sourcefile = gpd.read_file(source)
maskfile = gpd.read_file(mask)

clipshape = maskfile.explode()

clipshape.set_index('CATCH_NAME', inplace=True) # CATCH_NAME is attribute column name

for index, row in clipshape['geometry'].iteritems():
    clipped = gpd.clip(sourcefile, row)
    clipped.to_file(os.path.join(outpath, f'{index}.shp'))
```

Answer (score 2):

Two points

- https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/reference/api/geopandas.clip.html **mask** can be a *GeoDataFrame* hence no need for looping
- https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iterrows.html yields a **tuple** of the index value and named tuple of row.  Hence your error is the fact your are passing this **tuple** to `clip()`

Have constructed an example.  It is far simpler to clip using a *GeoDataFrame* as the mask.

```
import geopandas as gpd
import pandas as pd

# lets build a mask for use in clip, multipolygons and polygons
maskfile = gpd.read_file(gpd.datasets.get_path("naturalearth_lowres"))
maskfile = maskfile.loc[maskfile["continent"].eq("Europe") & maskfile["name"].ne("Russia")].pipe(
    lambda d: d.assign(gdp_grp=pd.cut(d["gdp_md_est"], bins=4, labels=list("abcd")))
).dissolve("gdp_grp").reset_index()

sourcefile = gpd.read_file(gpd.datasets.get_path("naturalearth_lowres"))

# now clip, no looping needed
gpd.clip(sourcefile, maskfile)
```

Comment: I was able to run the code with some modification but now I need to write each clipped polygon to specific folder with names based on the ID of the polygons in the multi-polygon shapefile `import geopandas as gpd

source = ('source-shapefile.shp')
mask = ('mask_shapefile.shp')
sourcefile = gpd.read_file(source)
maskfile = gpd.read_file(mask)
exploded = maskfile.explode(index_col = 'ID') for row in exploded['geometry']:
    gpd.clip(sourcefile, row)`

Comment: are you sure the operation you need is `clip()` and not `sjoin()`  Also what you describe is a many-many relationship.  How will that be treated in terms of filenames of output?

Comment: I edited my previous comment and added the code that was able do the job. but only thing now is that I need to save those files separately. so far i am here `clipped.to_file('shapefile'+int()+'.shp')`

Comment: Hi @AsifMarazi - check out the guide to [ask] - specifically, Rob Raymond did a great job answering your question, and if it solves the problem for you, you should mark it correct! The comment section isn't really a place to ask follow-up questions. If you have another question, feel free to post a new one :)

Comment: @MichaelDelgado yes Rob did his best and did a great Job and certainly helped me to figure out the problem but I think his answer was not the exact solution. I thank him anyway.